# Blank console upon trying to run cucumber feature file

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to run a Cucumber feature file by Right Click > Run As > Feature File. But no action is triggered. Blank console output.
What may be the case?

I have installed the following dependencies in pom.xml:

1. Junit
2. Cucumber-Java
3. Cucumber-Junit

[image]

Comment: The written steps do not seem to be mapped on to step definitions. Please show the complete eclipse window i.e., console as well

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure has to meet certain conditions to let cucumber run everything smoothly.

1. Put your feature file to `resources` folder
2. You step definition file(s) has to reside at the same package as your runner class (or in sub-packages)
3. Your feature file in `resource` folder has to be at the folder that reproduces package structure where your runner class is (or subfolders)

Say you have a package `my.test.package` where your runner class resides. That means that your feature file has to be under `resources/my/test/package` folder or its sub-folders. At the same time your step definition file has to be under `my.test.package` or its sub-packages.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on feature file -> Run as -> Run Configurations -> Cucumber Feature -> select the feature file -> Run